Error: Service Invoked too many times (Email Send)
I have a script that gets the specific draft from Gmail to send the email. It sent 10-15 emails and then started throwing error:

Service invoked too many times for one day: email.

Here is the code snippet:
function sendAutomatedEmails() {

  var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
  var draftEmail = drafts.find(draft => draft.getMessage().getSubject() == "Specific Email");
      if (draftEmail) {
        var emailBody = draftEmail.getMessage().getBody();
        var emailSubject = draftEmail.getMessage().getSubject();
        GmailApp.sendEmail("123@email.com", emailSubject, '', {htmlBody: emailBody});
      }
     }

The daily quota limit is 100/day, I am unsure why it stopped working after 10-15 emails. Now I did two things here:

I checked my quota using this:


Console.log(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()) 
//Output: -1



I tried again after 10 minutes and then it started sending emails again.

Now my questions are:

How the quota limit is reached when I sent only 10-15 emails and it is showing -1 as quota limit?

And why after 10 minutes, it starts sending emails again when the quota limit is -1?


I would really appreciate your guidance on how to avoid this issue, maybe by adding delay or anything else?

The daily quota for GmailApp is not just about the number of emails sent, but also the number of operations performed, like reading drafts. Every interaction with the Gmail service counts towards the quota. If your script performs multiple operations per email (e.g., multiple drafts reads), it can quickly add up.
Besides the daily send limit, there are additional limits on the number of read and write operations you can perform per minute or hour. Exceeding these can cause temporary suspensions, but once the period resets, you can start making requests again.
Although the email recipients per day limit is set to 100, this is subject to additional limitations unless your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD $100 (or equivalent) and at least 60 days have passed since reaching that payment threshold.
Spikes in a very short time can cause quota error even if the quota is not hit. In order to avoid the issues in the future, you can use exponential backoff to avoid hitting per-minute limits. Here is a sample code snippet that you can use in order to implement exponential backoff:
    function sendEmail() {

   var retries = 5; // Max no. of retries
   var baseDelay = 1000; // Initial delay in ms
   var success = false;

for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
   try {
   
   // Insert your code to send email here, for example
   // GmailApp.sendEmail(values['Email'], subject, emailBody, mailOptions);
   
   success = true;
   break; // Should the operation be successful, exit the loop
   
   } catch (e) {
     if (i == retries - 1) {
       throw e; // If this is the last retry, rethrow the exception
     }

   var delay = baseDelay * Math.pow(2, i); // Exponential backoff function
   Logger.log('Attempt ' + (i + 1) 'failed. Retrying in ' + delay + 'ms.');
   Utilities.sleep(delay);
   }
}

if (!success) {
   throw new Error('Failed to send email after ' + retries + 'attempts.');
   }
}

You can use the Gmail service instead of GmailApp due to its different usage limits. GmailApp is designed to be very easy to use within Google Apps Script. It provides straightforward methods for common tasks such as sending emails, reading messages and handling drafts. On the other hand, the Gmail service is essentially a library designed to interact with the Gmail API more conveniently.

thank you for your explanation, can we cut off the draft reading operation, may be by saving drafts in script properties and then use this instead of reading it directly through Gmail draft?
